# Sitecore Remove Broken Link From Treelist Field

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, broken-links

Is there a way to remove a deleted item from a treelist field. Everytime I try to remove the item, I get an message that says select an item.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the "Raw values" in the "View" tab of the content editor. This way all fields will show the actual value instead of the editing presentation. For the treelist, you will see the guid(s) that are selected and you can remove the faulty one.

Afterwards, just deselect the "raw values" again and it should be fixed.